# Google Drive image upload from android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to upload a image to google drive using API. I ve searched so much but i didn't find a way. I ve got a demo code which uploads a text file and it works. i need to change it to upload image.
This is the code...

```
public void CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(DriveContentsResult result){


    final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

    // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // write content to DriveContents
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            try {
                writer.write("Hello abhay!");
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("abhaytest2")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .setStarred(true).build();

            // create a file in root folder
            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

How can i change this code to upload a image from file.(by given location of the image in device).?
I ve found few tutorials but those are deprecated methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to upload image to google drive...

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                // Write the bitmap data from it.
                MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("image/jpeg").setTitle(title)
                        .build();
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(location));
                ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bitmapStream);
                try {
                    outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.i("E", "Unable to write file contents.");
                }
                image.recycle();
                outputStream = null;
                String title = "noisy";

                Log.i("E", "Creating new pic on Drive (" + title + ")");
                Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient,driveId)
                        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, metadataChangeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
```